# Installing JML in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jml

I am using Eclipse to program in Java. I tried installing from [this site](http://www.sct.ethz.ch/research/universes/tools/eclipse/) though Eclipse's Updater but although it didn't fire any error, I don't see the menus they say I should.

Maybe I have to install something first? Maybe there other simpler JML options? What you guys use?

Comment: You did use http://www.pm.inf.ethz.ch/research/universes/tools/eclipse/ as an update site, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have JDK installed (just Eclipse's stand-alone package). Installing the JDK and reinstalling JML in Eclipse did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the Error Log view and see if it contains any relevant errors.

Comment: I have a couple of errors but I don't think they are related with this update: http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/4466/jjox05sz1hflopjoeiawalv.png